# How to modify this command to install specific cuDNN and torch version "apt install libcudnn8"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, cuda, apt

this is my system :

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

I want to install cudnn 8.7.0 - i think exact version is 8.7.0.84_1

And also cuda11.7

this command : `apt install libcudnn8`

Installs  :  `Unpacking libcudnn8-dev (8.9.2.26-1+cuda12.1) over (8.5.0.96-1+cuda11.7) ...`

So how to modify `apt install libcudnn8`  so that it installs `cuDNN 8.7.0` and `Cuda 11.7`?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Nvidia docs (https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#package-manager-ubuntu-install):

```bash
sudo apt-get install libcudnn8=${cudnn_version}-1+${cuda_version}
sudo apt-get install libcudnn8-dev=${cudnn_version}-1+${cuda_version}
sudo apt-get install libcudnn8-samples=${cudnn_version}-1+${cuda_version}
```

Where:

- `${cudnn_version}` is for example 8.9.2.*
- `${cuda_version}` is for example cuda12.1 or cuda11.8

You can find a list of installable versions for example by running:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt list -a libcudnn8-dev
```

And then substitute the variables in the commands above with the commands that you require.

For RunPod you are logged into a docker container, and the `sudo` command is not installed so you can obviously drop the `sudo` prefix since you are logged in as the `root` user anyway, so for your specific use case on RunPod the command would be:

```
apt install libcudnn8=8.7.0.84-1+cuda11.8 libcudnn8-dev=8.7.0.84-1+cuda11.8
```

**Note**: Although you specifically specify CUDA 11.7, there is no available package to satisfy that particular requirement, which is why CUDA 11.8 was selected intead.

Answer (score 2):

Not all cuDNN and CUDA versions are available and CUDA version in nvidia-smi may say 12.0 even though you installed 12.2.

So, for example, below doesn't work:

```
# doesn't work
sudo apt-get install libcudnn8=8.9.4.25-1+cuda12.0
```

But this works:

```
sudo apt-get install libcudnn8=8.9.4.25-1+cuda12.2
```

To see available libcudnn8 versions see below:
https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/